# Why would you call yourself "the Sinister Iceman"?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-force

In Uncanny X-Force the X-Force travel to the Age of Apocalypse, an alternate universe where some of the good guys are evil and vice versa.  One of those who are on the evil side of things is Iceman.  However, in the comic he calls himself "the Sinister Iceman".  Why would you call yourself that?

Why not just call himself "Iceman", unless he is determined to be evil... but given the bad guys seem to be interested in forcing world evolution rather than being evil for the sake of being evil, it seems like a funny choice to dub yourself "Sinister".

[image]

Comment: "[Sinister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinister): Comes from the Latin _Sinistra_ meaning lefthand"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**He would call himself the 'Sinister Iceman' if he were from the [Age of Apocalypse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Apocalypse) Earth to differentiate himself from the normal Marvel Universe Iceman.**

Defining sinister (as AoA Iceman might have meant):

1. Suggesting or threatening evil: a sinister smile.
2. Presaging trouble; ominous: sinister storm clouds.
3. Attended by or causing disaster or inauspicious circumstances.

The world of the Age of Apocalypse is the Marvel-Earth #295, an alternative timeline from the normal Marvel Universe Earth #616. This alternative timeline has many of the same mutants that we recognize from the canon Marvel Universe, but on the AoA Earth, many of them are evil or sinister in nature. For a time the character known as [Dark Beast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Beast) came from the AoA Earth and replaced the Beast from Earth 616.

Mutants from the Age of Apocalypse Earth were amoral and believed in "the survival of the fittest" as was the credo of the mutant Apocalypse who ruled that world. Most mutants who worked with [Apocalypse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocalypse_%28comics%29) displayed the very worst of human behavior. Sinister would not even begin to cover the list of crimes most of them were guilty of.

The people from Earth #295 prided themselves on being bastards and might add such an appellation to inspire terror in their targets before killing them. It might also be a secret nudge by the writers to let us (the readers) know this is the AoA Iceman and not our Bobby Drake.

AoA Iceman has recently emerged on Earth-616 but his agenda is currently unknown.

Comment: But wouldn't he just consider himself "Iceman"?  It's only those of us aware of the multiple Icemans that need to distinguishing "Sinister" part.

Comment: Can you edit your comment into your answer?  I think the bit about priding themselves on being bastards is good extra info.